# Properly Scale UI Images in Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a png that's size 150x100 , and I set the UI image to the same, but it makes a bunch of extra space around it (that can be interacted with). How do I fix this?

Image of Problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57JfU.jpg

Comment: Can you show your settings from the Inspector for both the `Image` component and the texture import settings?

Comment: @derHugo The problem was that my image/graphic had extra transparents tiles, as shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity isn't adding extra space. The image itself HAS that space.

There are options to crop out the alpha space in Unity by using the sprite editor, but by my experience i prefer using a proper Image editor like Gimp. using one is the best way to handle your image assets.

To crop out the extra space you just have to reduce the canvas size.

Comment: how would I crop out the "alpha space" in unity in the sprite editor?

Comment: Sadly i don't really use the sprite editor, but it seems another option is to use scripts to manipulate the LineRenderer of the sprite: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/crop-2dsprite-unity

Answer (score -1):

<s>Well, first you could check (in Unity) wether your Image has its property `Preserve Aspect` set to `True`. 
You could click `Set Native Size` which is right below it, so the 'box' around your image will take it's size.</s>

Edit: Nevermind the first two. I do not know why i thought they could solve it, i looked at your image again and i, too, think there are transparent pixels above and below it. So you should try this:

Then you could check whether your picture has any transparent pixels around it, using an image editor. If it has, you would need to cut them out.

Comment: What should I try using?

Comment: i like paint.net, because its free and in my opinion easy to use. You could use many other tools too, like gimp.